# Cambiar activity al iniciar sesión

Tags: android, login, activity

espero estén bien. Estoy trabajando en una App, esta consta de 3 activitys informativos antes de la pagina de login. Mi pregunta es... ¿Como le hago para que cuando el usuario ya esté loggeado no me aparezcan esas 3 activitys al cerrar la app completamente? Graciaaas.

Comment: Hola @Erik Hernandez, te recomiendo que leas [ask] para poder realizar una pregunta de calidad para que te podamos ayudar y léete esto también para conocer el sitio y sus normas [tour]

Answer (score -1):

Debes hacer dos cosas, la primera es guardar una bandera cuando se inicia sesion, puede ser el id del usuario, su correo o cualquier cosa que consideres adecuado, esto lo guardas a los `SharedPreferences` con el siguiente codigo:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("TAG", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPrefs.edit().putString("CLAVE",VALOR).apply();
```

Luego, en el primer `activity` de los tres que mencionas, debes validar que el valor que guardaste exista, si existe, inicias el `activity` principal, eso se hace mas o menos asi:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("TAG", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String valor = sharedPref.getString("CLAVE", "VALOR_POR_DEFECTO");
    Intent intent;

    /* Si el valor guardo es diferente al valor por defecto, significa que ya inicio sesion
     *  asi que lo puedes enviar al main
     */
    if (!valor.equals("VALOR_POR_DEFECTO")) {
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    //Puedes hacerlo antes de pintar tu layout, asi no se hara tan rapido que no se notara
    setContentView(R.layout.tu_layout);
}
```

Solo recuerda que debes borrar el valor cuando el usuario cierre sesion, de lo contrario no funcionara al volver a abrir la aplicacion.

Answer (score -2):

Para lograr lo que quieres puedes utilizar un intent haciendo uso del método **addFlags()**. A este método tienes que pasarle como parámetro diferentes constantes de la clase Intent.

Al utilizar este método la actividad que lances queda siendo la principal, por lo que al abrir la app esta será la que se lance.

Si tienes dos actividades, la actividad MainActivity y la actividad SegundaActivity. Desde el MainActivity lanzas la actividad SegundaActivity utilizando en el intent el metodo addFlags(), la actividad SegundaActivity quedara como la actividad principal. De ese modo al abrir la aplicación, esta se abrira con la SegundaActivity por defecto.

Ej:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    public void loginButton(View view) {

        // Coloca este fragmento de codigo donde quieras lanzar 
        // la actividad para que quede configurada como la actividad principal. 
        // Como por ejemplo en el boton de login o cuando confirmes que el  
        // usuario se ah logueado correctamente.
        Intent intent_Login = new Intent(this, SegundaActivity.class);
        intent_Login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent_Login);

    }
}
```

SegundaActivity

```
public class SegundaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.segunda_activity);

    }
}
```